# Tips for solving: Construct a $\delta_1, \delta_2$ such that $\frac{2(A_1\delta_2+\delta_1 A_2)}{A_2^{\ 2}-\delta_2^{\ 2}} \lt \varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

For any $A_1, A_2, \varepsilon \gt 0$ I would like to construct $0 \lt \delta_1 \lt A_1$ and $0 \lt \delta_2 \lt A_2 $ such that the following statement is true:

$$\frac{2(A_1\delta_2+\delta_1 A_2)}{A_2^{\ 2}-\delta_2^{\ 2}} \lt \varepsilon$$

I've played around with the problem a little bit, but I have not had much success. It seems to me that I am going to have to run through a few different cases related to relative sizes (e.g. $A_1 \gt A_2$ or $A_1 \lt A_2$, etc) and magnitudes relative to $1$ (e.g. $\varepsilon \lt 1$ or $\varepsilon \geq 1$, etc).

Is there a efficient way of carrying out this calculation?

I first considered the case of $\varepsilon \geq 1$, and set up the following equation:

$$\frac{2(A_1\delta_2+\delta_1 A_2)}{A_2^{\ 2}-\delta_2^{\ 2}} \lt 1$$

Rearranging and completing the square for $A_2$ and $\delta_2$, I produced the equation:

$$(\delta_2+A_1)^2-A_1^{ \ 2} -(A_2-\delta_1)^2+\delta_1^{\ 2} \lt 0$$

$$(\delta_2+A_1)^2+(\delta_1^{\ 2}-A_1^{ \ 2})-(A_2-\delta_1)^2 \lt 0$$

Even from here, though, it looks like the computation will be fairly messy as I have to start comparing magnitudes across several terms.

Any tips/tricks would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to find $\delta_1, \delta_2$ given $\varepsilon > 0$? It seems to me that the statement you're trying to prove is false. For instance, if there were such $\delta$'s, let $\varepsilon$ be the LHS of the inequality, then it's false.

Comment: @fwd Yes, that is what I am trying to find. I am not sure I follow what you mean by "Let $\varepsilon$ be the LHS of the inequality". Could you explain further?

Comment: If you are trying to find deltas for given epsilon such that the inequality holds, you're good. But there can't be deltas so that the inequality holds for every $\varepsilon >0$. Your first sentence seems to say this but that's not what you mean.

Comment: @fwd ohhh, sorry for the sloppiness. I'll rephrase accordingly.  Cheers~

Comment: @S.Cramer In cases like this you do not have to "*construct*" $\delta_{1,2}$ in the sense that  you don't need to come up with an explicit formula for them. You just need to prove that you *can* find such values. Also, you have complete freedom in choosing whatever  form makes it easier to prove the existence. For example, choosing $\delta_1=\delta_2=\delta$ the expression becomes $\,\frac{2\delta(A_1+A_2)}{A_2^{\ 2}-\delta^{\ 2}}\,$ which $\to 0$ when $\delta \to 0$, so you can always find a $\delta$ such that the expression is $\lt \varepsilon\,$, and that's all you need.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for the input! I assume an example of "prove that you can find such values" is the method that the accepted answer (from Michael Barz) employed. When I use your trick of $\delta_1=\delta_2=\delta$, I guess I just have to make sure that the conditions originally applied *separately* to $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ are now applied *together* with $\delta$ (i.e. $0 \lt \delta \lt A_1 \land 0 \lt \delta \lt A_2)$.

Comment: @S.Cramer That's correct. And $\,\delta\,$ can be chosen arbitrarily small, so satisfying the additional conditions is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this up into two terms, and instead try to make both
$$\frac{2A_1\delta_2}{A_2^2 - \delta_2^2} < \frac{\epsilon}{2},$$
and
$$\frac{2A_2\delta_1}{A_2^2 - \delta_2^2} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
true. Let's start with the first inequality, since it depends only on $\delta_2.$

As $\delta_2\rightarrow 0,$ we have $2A_1\delta_2/(A_2^2-\delta_2^2)\rightarrow 0,$ so by picking $\delta_2$ small we can get your first inequality. With $\delta_2$ fixed so that the first inequality is true, just pick $\delta_1$ so that

$$\delta_1 < \frac{\epsilon}{4A_2}(A_2^2-\delta_2^2),$$
and you're done.

Comment: Just for clarification, you're making use of the fact that:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{\delta_2 \to 0} \frac{2A_1\delta_2}{A_2^{\ 2}-\delta_2^{\ 2}}=0$$, which means that there is some $\delta^*_{\varepsilon/2}$ such that if $|\delta_2|=\delta_2 \lt \delta^*_{\varepsilon/2}$, then $\frac{2A_1\delta_2}{A_2^{\ 2}-\delta_2^{\ 2}} \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Is that correct?

Comment: @S.Cramer Yes, and that limit follows since the denominator tends to $A_2^2 > 0$ but the numerator tends to 0.

Comment: Yup yup. Great tip! Thank you very much ~~. For notation purposes, I would just add that we could alternatively stipulate that because $\delta_2 \lt \delta^*_{\varepsilon/2}$ (and both are positive), we have that $-\delta_2^{\ 2} \gt -\left(\delta^*_{\varepsilon/2}\right)^2$, which means that:

$$\frac{\varepsilon}{4A_2}\left( A_2^{\ 2}-\delta_2^{\ 2}\right) \gt \frac{\varepsilon}{4A_2}\left( A_2^{\ 2}-\left(\delta^*_{\varepsilon/2}\right)^2\right)=C$$

So if we demand that: $\delta_1 \lt C$, we are good to go.